# Android Studio: App Icon

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app which drops down a menu once the user has pressed the app icon (located on the left of the action bar). However I am having difficulty with making the app icon clickable. The closes I have gotten is using:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()
```

However this doesn't make my app icon clickable, rather, it applies a left arrow.

Code:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: Can you post an image of your actionbar with the icon?

Comment: I think you will need to set a custom view for your action bar and put an imageView of your app icon that reacts as a button.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view for your actionBar like the following and modify it for your needs:

Java Code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actonbar_layout, null);

actionBar.setCustomView(view);

ImageView appIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.appIcon);
appIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Open your menu here...
    }
});
```

actionbar_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/appIcon"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/appName" />

</LinearLayout>
```